# Airport or airports which have hot water springs or public baths inside the airport itself?

Tags: airports, where-on-earth

I read about an airport some days back (forgot which one it is) which has a hot spring in it. I forgot where it is, but in the Middle East.

Does anybody know of the airport I'm talking about?

Curious to know if there is more than one airport which has amenities such as a hot spring or/and public baths.

Comment: Not 'public' as in free and open to all, though. I'm sure you can think of plenty hygiene reasons why. Leprosy still exists in some parts of the world, for example.

Answer (score 5):

You may be thinking of [The Hilton Fit & Fly Spa](http://www.munich-airport.de/en/consumer/aufenthalt_trans/gesHyg/wellness/hilton_fit_spa/index.jsp) in the Munich Airport:

> You are in between flights and looking for a place to relax? The Hilton fit & fly SPA invite you to reload in the 17m pool, whirlpool, sauna, steam bath and the fitness center with a convenient 2 hour SPA card.

Comment: possible, looking at that.

Comment: @pnuts I didn't see the "middle-east" edit until now. I suggest you post an answer.

Comment: And now I see this is off-topic, which I thought might happen. Nevermind about posting.